# Latest LAMP stack for RasPi 3

Tags: web-server

I'm new to the Raspi and this site.  Working from Eben Upton's 2012 book, the suggestion to set up a LAMP STACK for a simple web server (chapter 6, p 124) seems out of date.  Does anybody know the latest correct command set please? Also, my pi doesn't have the examples CPU/GRU memory partitioning files, but I'm guessing that the start.elf file may now do this somehow? Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=218354

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Foundation has a number of useful tutorials which work with current Raspbian.

The following documents a Web Server (I use `NGINX`)
https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/web-server/README.md

> The instructions for `nginx` reference `php5` - this is obsolete in Stretch `php7` is now default.
>
> If you follow the instructions (edit the files - but ignore changed content) it works.

You can set up L?MP on Apache2 or NGINX by following
https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/lamp-web-server-with-wordpress

There is no need to go as far as Wordpess if you just want the stack.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer - I will pursue your suggestions. Mike