# Raspberry Pi: Host a Site That Can Be Viewed by Access Point Devices

Tags: networking, ethernet, web-server, access-point, web-interface

I am thinking of making a Raspberry Pi project in which my Raspberry Pi acts as a special WiFi access point that is connected to my home router. Devices connected to the access point will NOT have access to the Internet OR my home network. My question is complex, but I will do my best to describe it.
 Would it be possible for this Raspberry Pi to host a site that can be accessed by devices connected to the access point **in addition** to hosting a **separate** site that can be accessed by devices connected to my home network?
One more less important question: Could I possibly make these sites accessible by Bonjour (raspberrypi.local)?
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: captive portal on unencrypted wifi with dhcpd

Comment: In general it seems do be possible. It depends on what you want in detail.You write: "*.. host a site that can be accessed by devices connected to the access point in addition to hosting a separate site that can be accessed by devices connected to my home network*". Is there a difference between the network from the AP and the home network? Isn't the AP, including devices connected to it, part of the home network (bridged)? Or are there two different subnets (routing)? Please address me with @Ingo, otherwise I won't see your reply.

Comment: OK, you want an isolated wifi subnet. Do you want to use two web server, one for each web site? Or do you want to use one web server, serving both (different) web sites? Where should it/they run? On a device on the wifi network, on the Raspi or on a device on the home network? Everything is possible.

Comment: I want both of the sites to be hosted by the Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 1):

An Access Point is NOT a router. See **Using the Raspberry Pi as an access point to share an internet connection (bridge)** in [Access Point](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md)

Adding an Access Point to an existing network just adds complication, and a normal network does not need one. If you do implement an Access Point **DO NOT implement a DHCP server - use the server on your router** - thus all devices should be on the same network segment.

You can host on the Pi. See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/90864/8697 for links to tutorials. I use `nginx` to host on my Pi, accessible by `hostname.local`.

Raspbian by default implements [Zero-conf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking). Whether other devices on your network support this is not a Pi issue.

I suggest you implement whatever you plan to do in stages.